# How do I learn to strafe jump in Quake3?

Tags: quake-3

I have read tutorials, watched videos, still can not strafe jump (movement by bunny hopping with gained speed) in Quake 3.

Do I need specially made maps for it to work?

Is there some settings I need to change server- or client-sided?
Perhaps a good tutorial showing hand movement and keyboard, mouse rhythm and coordination?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Quake Live](http://www.quakelive.com/#home) features a [strafe jumping tutorial map](http://www.quakelive.com/#practice/training/p2h1) with screenshots and videos of each "puzzle."

A video of the map being cleared can be seen [here.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-RleSYaLB0#t=10)

Comment: Nice! Never thought of Quake Live. Gonna try it at home.

Comment: This has been awesomely helpful. The training grounds are tough to master, though. Thank you.

Comment: This video is unavailable :/

Answer (score 6):

Note Quake Live has slightly different movement physics than the original Quake III Arena.

The best way to learn how to strafe-jump in Q3A is to install DeFRaG mod ([download link](https://q3defrag.org/files/defrag/)) and practice on `opc1` map ([download link](https://ws.q3df.org/map/opc1/)). The very beginning may be a bit frustrating and difficult, but after you will pass that map, you will know how to make strafe jumps properly.

Following tips may help:

- Read Strafing Tutorial ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190806000130/http://www.trickingq3.com/Tutorials/Strafing_Tutorial.html))

## YouTube videos

You may also watch following YouTube tutorials:

**Steve's StrafeJump Tutorial for Quake 3 (on the `opc1` map)**

**No-Bullshit Strafejump Tutorial. [Diabotical, Quake 3, Quake Live, Quake Champions]**

**Genesis – The Beginning Of** - see how to use DeFRaG configuration for feedback on your jumps (pressed keys, last jump speed, etc.)

You may also enable Camping Gaz HUD in DeFRaG. It's a bit complex HUD, but it may helps you to get immediate feedback on your movement and strafe jumping.

Comment: @downvoter: Can you add your rationale for downvote, please?

Comment: Don't forget to enable the Camping Gaz HUD. It helps A LOT. Plus I recommend using the long downhill map with the gap at the end to learn.